# Advice on adding JLabels to a rectangle in Java

Tags: java, swing

We are making a UML tool as part of our undergraduate project. The way we handle attributes drawn on screen is as follows:

1. Every thing is drawn on a JPanel that has a grid drawn on it.
2. The reference of this JPanel is passed to the item that is to be drawn such as a class or interface whatever..
3. Then we simply draw the shape(by drawRect) and when attributes are added, we simply add JLabels representing them on the JPanel by using the reference passed in point 2. But to user it appears they are drawn on the shape.
   **My question is that, is our method right? Or is there a better way to achieve this task? I am attaching a diagram illustrating what we have? Or is it a bad idea to use JLabel for this task? The reference of JPanel is only passed to draw JLabels. It is not needed otherwise.** 
   [image: class2 and attributes all are JLabels. User can change their visibility and name by right click and left click respectively]

Comment: This is a fairly subjective question due to the fact that there are multiple ways of doing this and there may not be an objective way of determining which method is the best.

Comment: My feeling is that once you start drawing on a JPanel, you keep drawing on a JPanel.  In other words, use drawText methods rather than JLabels.  As rcook said in his answer, you want to keep all the drawing code for an object together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are saying that the JLabels holding attributes are placed on the big JPanel that has the grid.

I agree with the commenter that says this is subjective, but I have an alternative to offer you that I think is so MUCH better that it deserves being an answer.  You have a rectangular space on your overall drawing that represents one item -- an object, in this case.  I would think it likely that either now or in the future you are going to want to do things with this item, and if you draw the components of the item separately, you are going to have committed yourself to keeping up with all its subitems in your own code.

I suggest, instead, having a JPanel that represents the object, and placing any attributes or anything else to be displayed within that rectangle on the object's JPanel, not the grid's JPanel.

Comment: May be we shall be using JComponent as parent class for our drawing elements in our context to solve the above problem. Agreed with your explanation and thought.